# Two column layout. Scrolling anywhere on the page should scroll the right column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a two column website, however the user must focus in on the right column to scroll the main content. If the user is focused on the left-hand link bar nothing happens. I tried coding a script that will scroll the right column no matter where the user's mouse is. It does not feel natural and barely scrolls.

Here is my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/knfg9Lqp/4/

Here is my website(scroll only works on right div): [maxmastalerz.com](https://www.maxmastalerz.com/Blog)

**How could I go about making it non-laggy and fluid with the right amount of scroll?**

I could probably use a [plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel), however I'm leaning away from that idea.

```js
$(document).bind('mousewheel', function(e){
    var delta = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta/120)*3;
    var y = $('#right').scrollTop();  //your current y position on the page
    $('#right').scrollTop(y-delta);
});
```

```css
#left {
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
}
#right {
  background-color: aqua;
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="left">
  <a href="/one">Link 1</a>
  <a href="/two">Link 2</a>
  <a href="/three">Link 3</a>
</div>

<div id="right">
  "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
</div>


TRY SCROLLING UP AND DOWN USING YOUR MOUSEWHEEL OR TOUCHPAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you dividing and multiplying? If you simply use `var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;` the scrolling looks right

https://jsfiddle.net/knfg9Lqp/5/

Comment: It's about twice as fast as my typical scroll, I guess that doesn't matter so much though...

Comment: You could divide by 2 or 1.5 to slow the scroll down

Comment: I wonder if that's platform dependant. Maybe that's where the plugin comes in. I uploaded the changes to the site. Tell me what your opinion on it is. You might have to clear your cache

Comment: Seems pretty normal on chrome